# Display raw PNG from MySQL in ImageView

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, blob

I get a BLOB data from a Mysql database using jdbc, i store it like a string. I had tried to decode to  Base64 but i get a error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

My code:

```
if(tipoColumnas.get(i).equals("BLOB")){
            Log.d("BLOB", columnas.get(i));
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(columnas.get(i).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            holder.ivListaDeCeldas.get(i).setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
        }
```

My Log shows me:

```
D/BLOB: ‰PNG

������IHDR������y������������åZÙe������ pHYs����Ã����ÃÇo¨d���� ��IDATxœL»w”$gyÿ»÷{~¾FawgwrÎ=fz¦{¦'vÎ9TUWÎ9tîž°I«•V9"AB0Ñ°IL°1ÙÁ`„PZíîLÝ?¸·ÎsÞSõÖuÎç¼õ<Ï÷ûV»|é­—/½õ®Ëo½tç£·_~ôÎ{Þré®7_ºÿÍgn¿÷âŸ={Ù0:’¬ƒ`¥R.Š��0"€Q A8VDÈN•    H€ÀòS¦©"   g`Ài Ë8YÆÃË0¡d!Ëb4��3%-•ÉL†Éf¨lšÎ¥ÊÍ²ùñDÍÅÙ\\Î'´rR.Ä˜D°^)@VÉEÕRB-%ØLÍù\˜I…øtŒODÔlR/dØdD.¦¥rF,%™l„)$˜¿ÙÁâ ¸ÉSd>QI‰BŠ.f˜rI¬ „‘E˜.£"ÁeŒ†HÀé
ÎÀ:­Š(O•     Xg+&²Ç
\…ã*R,DãE‡¨È’~îü¥»î}è®‡½ðÀ÷<úÈ±».¿íò_¸øð¥»½|ï[ÎÝqÿ…Ëž½xçÞ™Ût­EáPDK`��ÁK(    àx  ÅKQÆ‰2ŽP Ð2F^@ÉNÄ»€Óe”,Âlc”G(Å"žËâ™‘N–Û€lÐñ˜ÉùDÌµp …C5¸$2B)Mg‚B>$äCB>‚%6á¸—HmÓ©:µÃfütÂÇ¥ƒl<ÀÆ\,@Åüt2Èd#hÂG¤ƒT6ÌdcL"È§#r6Æ¥Â|:ÂebB)e#Åð&‘‰Â±™ÏPÅS.³0ÂV0
Âœaœ1@(��g@ŠH¶B±‚†H
$iˆ"‚I¦B³Í€R|…á š…ic¡"ŒTðZµÕÚÝ»çÑGîzø¡cç/>zû¿ýKw=|pñ®3·ÝÑè¢J“\*œ.¦JH    Å��/¡d£��œ*D¿ñ$´€`E”pÀ1��'Ê8tg /‚teW†˜bI‚A²˜Æóq$Îú×ÀÈ6É€RJéPºC¢¨CiÊòÅVb~ ä£²i&“r    &bA4¸MÆýt2HeÃH|xAß°³
û×Kx{Üö–ýëåÀÙ)‡6so%€ÂÛhÌOÆƒl:|#˜l„Ì„¨\„âZ%#–â"b
    º˜¢J²œÇ
9¦2†@��iá`’1ÂI%A”©PL…¢’ ¦Y˜&Ê‘H± ÅÃ,3T…q¡R¨”‹%E“î±K÷¿åÒ½ž½tZkÉŠAS|&ž…Ë()Dò0VDq'/"7c��Ž–1(_!Ê8R„A8QBÙ2*–+|±Ì•Ë\¾HÄ“h(€¶¨D€ËG”JºÍBmºRƒj1¥’\&"æãdÊO'ƒX"_wÓ¥|S€X¬Åñí¾'úzOŽôNNöœ89?:;Ó?á™µlÚìk³³›óïÌìÚôŒÏfß¶Ù¶Žu›mÝf[µXÖm6¯Õº2;»<5åôÛm¡%»Ï:]qd¶<©•ÔÆJ9°A&vØŒŸHú°¤ŸÊÅ˜|˜ÎEØb’3L9ED>Ã”K<Tæ@€«ThaAœ.ãDS��NC$’B0N8Q,D³M4lE !Š‚)Æ*%øØù;P¶È©„c��VJ—€"0´Œa��Ž”¤„ /¡L%”p¢Ð2†43��ÁU0ª\áW©`Ù–‰—›h4Pö¯Q‰€d[p±çÏòhùˆ˜±Éˆ–Ïp±‰”|;!Ïò¦Ãá[Yƒ¢ÙÇ.ÜÝ Å‰‘Áÿ¦ÝnmGÞzûƒ_†Îáåpá®ÎS'§ÇNÏL–¼+s;¶Å°k%îöD\Ë!·+äZ¹\ÅÅm«Ý3;ç™ó;ƒÎ¥‹m{Þº½`Ý²Z]ãã~»Ã;7³m[ð9"nGzÓ]ð{‹54áÃâÛT:Àä£T&Ê“t)Id6&”óPä!ˆ-CT a��ŒI"y„¡��œ©PL…¦@š…X
$yT @š©°4D±0C$Uañœ—Q0Ý(eh¾‚ƒT¬  vcs ’T™ÀVDá\/¡L…Â‹ÀØbE��A2ŸÁ³   ¦”ÎûÖˆtÉF¤rb—.jt+¥¤’‹òÉ��ÛÖóI"èËm¬oÌÛæûÆæû§–']>—qÊÝó×CŽY72>ÏöÚŠÛ¿±á¶9“¡Ôªs}bÊ¹¹)„·Ýùv0ILM.ö›êŸuN9ÝóÎr$Î‹X†£~8@C8 ³ÉbÈ_ŠËÁ ¼›é•µ¬w3áYÚ‘EWÈ±è[°mZ¬ÛVûÖ‚mÛjß¶ÙB.GÂëÊl¹s[«@pñDJ‡¸L„ËÄðD/fÙBŽ.y "@_!9ˆ` /¡ÂR M,3L…¦@’åhˆdaš©c¥t- T™Àr0Q@©ND¥WJ0+%¸R¨à%Œ,áh¶‚º‚3*ažÉŠ��ÀòHÔWò¯£   –Ü¡²þ&]ê²J‹¥8™
òÙ¨THI¹$òÅv÷ÔÄÚüüø­§ç{&o×.œåÏF\É©SÖûödô§Þý‘¯~äÓÅíhhÃgŸ·¹K­àððô›NZ,Ë½½£T…ôòc³ÓKËKÛ}§'-s®ž“}§O­-Ú}î¥”NFèl’Ë¥¹B
I…átŠàhÇ ô‡àH   Gá@��Üö×·³ë;éµ­àâÊêô¼gjÎ56arOMmZ¬>»3î^-îlƒ-,ì§:&“*“ 3i:—cóE®ÐE€…P¶BP ACsÆ³0s£rÃÁ4Pd;†Q¼„±f"“‚(ãH    …\„1��CË(’¯P��NP¡ðÀC](à©™Ž–T"$·éÌ„4È‚XŽJÅ›“ÚŠ{}Öy÷ø˜{lÂ7·°66³84=ß;¹§žùÎ?¿ì‡³Þœª¿úö/~ø•ï|â½Llúoéë?=ÚsbxzÂöW7v/í`)âá3ÆãÅ‰G«~Æb]ó³}ùò¦ÓwúäÀÀàpßp¿Íjñ:í`,Ì³|1ÍCÙJ*ˆæBp*Hg“T:…'’d*M¥Sx<Æ&3T2Ex"U G‘p‹&²kÛéµ­à¢Ç;ïØ´.;Ff¼³[Vkhq)í]Ëo¯Cá<Fãa,£³ÉÐéR‰«`7Z¢°"N1,D³JDX¾BŠ{Œ(
```

So i insert image in Base64 and still have error:

```
D/BLOB: ï»¿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
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Comment: Is it stored in Base64? That binary junk could be a PNG.

Comment: Can you explain me what is that all code unteligible that i show in the Log, i didnt store the image but i think its in PNG format

Comment: Like I said, that could be a raw PNG. I don't know because I can't decode it from that mangled form.

Comment: so if the image is stored in png or jpg, how can i parse or get that image

Comment: What do you mean "get that image"? It's PNG image data. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: show it in a ImageView, in android, i get that BLOB column value with the method getString(), using jdbc resultSet

Comment: Why do you assume it is encoded in base64 at all? A blob contains binary data, and doesn't need to be base64 encoded (that would be inefficient). Remove it and use the byte array directly.